# JQuery .on() event handler usage for dynamically loaded image

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

My pages are generating dynamically by ajax response.

Each response has an `img` element with specified id. I need them to fade in when loaded.

`.load()` and `.bind('load')` works fine when page is loaded for first time. But not working in next response for sure.

```
$('#my_img').load(function(){
   $(this).hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

So i need to use `.on()` event handler. But doesn't work.

```
$('body').on('load','#my_img',function(){
   $(this).hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Note: This is not a cache issue. Img src also has a random query string.

Comment: The load event doesn't bubble, and as such can't be delegated, so what you're trying to do can't be done !

Comment: How about binding the handler inside `.load()` methods handle..?

Comment: You could still capture event to body level

Comment: You can bind the handler to the image directly before adding the ajax response to the page. If you add the code for how the response is added to the page, we can probably help you out with that.

Comment: Simply, rebind the on method in the AJAX call back to the image, or whatever element you need.

Comment: @adeneo Thank you.
@rdubya, @T J Yes i can do that. I just thought it would be good practice if i could do with `.on()`. But seems i can't. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`onload` event doesn't bubble, so you cannot delegate it. But, if you don't need to support IE8<, you can capture event instead which will work for any dynamic img:

```
document.body.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function(event){
        var elm = event.target;
        if( elm.id === 'my_img'){ // or any other filtering condition
            // do some stuff
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: Thank you. This one will work. I dont need to support ancient browser and its users :)

Answer (score -1):

You could try using Jquery's ready event instead of on.load to run some code when the element is ready.

Here's a fiddle I made to demonstrate it in action:    https://jsfiddle.net/yosefh/66g0xjre/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div').click(function() {
    var newDiv = $('<div></div>');
      $(newDiv).ready(function() {
        $(newDiv).fadeIn("slow");
      });
      $('body').append(newDiv);
    });
});
```