# Can't get load() to work on img

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before I start I know this may be a duplicate. I have looked at the solution of the following:

[jQuery .load() not working on my image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588102/jquery-load-not-working-on-my-image)

and changed my code. However I still can't get the load to fire. I've tried changing the `.load` to `.on('load' ...)` and basically butchered my code trying to get this working... I still can't get the `alert()` to fire... Any ideas?

```
<html>
   <head>
   <title>XXX</title>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="outter">
         <div id="selectionBox">
                <form id="qqqq" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/" method="post">
<input id="fileSelect" onchange="readURL(this);" type="file" name="imagePP" accept="image/x-png, image/gif, image/jpeg, image/bmp">
             </form>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
   <script>  
        function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    if (!$("#aaa").length)
                        $("body").append("<img id=\"aaa\">");

                    $("#aaa").attr('src', e.target.result);
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#aaa").load(function() {
                alert("sdffds");
            }).each(function() {
                if (this.complete) {
                    $(this).trigger('load');
                }
            });
        });
   </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Because you are attaching the event handler before the image is added to the page.

Comment: `id`s must be unique. It looks like you are using multiple times. Not the exact issue. But that is not a good practice.

Comment: Rejith I don't see any id duplication? which one?

Comment: Hi Epascarello, I thought it would still be picked up even if elements with the id are dynamically added?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery .on() event handler usage for dynamically loaded image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332423/jquery-on-event-handler-usage-for-dynamically-loaded-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure but your image tag should bind to the document when calling document.ready(). The readURL() function is not called from anywhere which actually create the img tag.

Comment: sorry i missed the <input> line when editing. please see now

Comment: look into the below code - document.body.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function(event){
        var elm = event.target;
        if( elm.id === 'my_img'){ // or any other filtering condition
            // do some stuff
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);

Comment: already answered in the following thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27332423/jquery-on-event-handler-usage-for-dynamically-loaded-image

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).on("load", "#aaa", function() {
```

As a way to bind the `load` event to `#aaa`
This way, dynamically added `#aaa` elements still get the event bound to them.

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/4b8340gu/
Please check out this jsFiddle with slight changes to your code that make it work.

I've placed the .load declaration in readURL.